# PHP is changing the element style height of a div

Tags: php, html, css

My PHP is changing the element style of a div that is given to that div using javascript. I have no idea why. I tried troubleshooting it and it didn't work.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be, or how to change the php to not have that problem.

PHP Code (DB-connect.php):

```
<?php
  $server = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "";
  $dbname = "portfolio";

  $connect = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $dbname);
  if (!$connect) {
    die("Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  $opl = "SELECT begin, eind, opleiding, school, beschrijving FROM opleidingen";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $opl);

mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

PHP in main file

```
<?php
  include 'inc/db-connect.php';
?>
<?php
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo '<h3> $row["school"] </h3>';
    } 
  }
?>
```

Javascript init code for the dynamic background size:

```
$('header').css({ 'height': $(window).height() });

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('header').css({ 'height': $(window).height() });
    $('body').css({ 'width': $(window).width() })
});
```

I've tried changing the php up or changing the javascript, but I could not troubleshoot it.

Comment: PHP cannot affect the HTML markup or CSS in any way except to output exactly the HTML you code it to. View the page source of your output and examine it closely to see what is incorrect in the HTML.   In particular, this does not work as you intend: `echo '<h3> $row["school"] </h3>';`.  Because it is a single-quoted string, you will see the literal string `"$row["school"]"` in your HTML, not the expanded PHP variable.

Comment: Also, you are immediately calling `mysqli_close()` in the connection file. Since you close it, PHP will be unable to retrieve result rows from the `$result` resource in main.php.  It is almost never necessary to explicitly call `mysqli_close()` as PHP will do so automatically. Remove that line.

Comment: Always when developing and testing code, enable PHP's error display. It would be complaining about the above issue, possibly others. At the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`